# Запиь свойства в обьект JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать проверку для обьекта и записать в него свойство.
Если обьект существует то записываем в него свойство, если такого обьекта нет, то создаем обьект и записываем в созданый обьект свойство, как можно реализовать такоую проверку лаконично?

```
if(json.pupilFields) 
    json.pupilFields[field] = staticItems[field] 
else { 
    json.pupilFields = {} 
    json.pupilFields[field] = staticItems[field] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj;

(obj = obj || {}).prop = 123;

console.log(obj);
```

Это

```
if(json.pupilFields) 
  json.pupilFields[field] = staticItems[field]; 
else { 
  json.pupilFields = {}; 
  json.pupilFields[field] = staticItems[field]; 
}
```

можно переписать как

```
(json.pupilFields = json.pupilFields || {})[field] = staticItems[field];
```

Comment: `if(json.pupilFields)
                  json.pupilFields[field] = staticItems[field]
                 else {
                  json.pupilFields = {}
                  json.pupilFields[field] = staticItems[field]
                 }`
это можно как то проще переписать?

Comment: спасибо большое за быстрый ответ!